# How to display ArticleResults in a ListView

Tags: xamarin.android

I am new in developing android application and I am having this error "Argument 3: cannot convert from 'NewsAPI.Models.ArticlesResult' to 'int'" while trying to put the ArticleResults in a listview, Could you guys please help me solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
        var newsApiClient = new NewsApiClient("574c805a2730461ba4e8243dc3ca0519");
        ArticlesResult articlesResponse = newsApiClient.GetEverything(new EverythingRequest
        {
            Q = "Ultraviolet",
            SortBy = SortBys.PublishedAt,
            Language = Languages.EN,
        });

        mList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List);
        ArrayAdapter<ArticlesResult> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ArticlesResult>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, articlesResponse);
```

Comment: which line of code is throwing the error here?

Comment: ArrayAdapter<ArticlesResult> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ArticlesResult>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, articlesResponse);

This line sir

Comment: Are you sure, I do not see any issue here!

Comment: Yes sir, 
As you can see in this link, I screen shot the actual code
https://ibb.co/D7Z0yBs

Comment: Oh now I see it, it is not working because the Third parameter is supposed to be a collection and `ArticlesResult` is a single object not a collection

Comment: With that, what can you suggest in order to achieve what I needed ?

Comment: What are you receiving from the API

Comment: Thank you for your Answers G. Hakim, but this question has been answered in my Forum in Xamarin.. 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/156647/hi-i-want-to-display-articleresults-inside-a-listview-how-could-i-achieve-it